# Sql cast to float without scientific notation

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I cast a decimal value to float without getting the result in scientific notation?

For example, if my value is `0.000050` as a decimal, when I cast it to float I get `5E-05`

I would like to see `0.00005`

Comment: Which flavor of SQL? Is this for Oracle? DB2? SQL Server? MySQL? Postgres? Something else entirely? Those things are highly vendor-specific - please let us know what concrete database you're using by updating the tags of your question accordingly!

Comment: @Amirreza Keshavarz Real had the same effect as float.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This has nothing to do with converting to float. It has to do with converting to text. You need to look at the [`str()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) function:

```
str( float_expression , total-width , number-of-decimal-places )
```

where

- *float-expression* means what you think it means,
- *total-width* is the total field width desired, including sign, decimal place, etc.
- *number-of-decimal-places* is the number of decimal places displayed (0-16). If more than 16 is specified, the formatted value is truncated (not rounded) at 16 decimal places.

In your case, something like:

```
declare @value float = 0.000050
select str(@value,12,6)
```

should do you.

Edited to note: the `str()` function will not display anything in scientific notation. If the problem is that you want to trim trailing zeroes from the decimal value, you can do two things:

- Use the `format()` function (SQL Server 2012 only):

  ```
  declare @x decimal(18,6) = 123.010000
  select @x                        as x1 ,
         format(@x,'#,##0.######') as x2 , -- all trailing zeroes trimmed
         format(@x,'#,##0.000###') as x3   -- min of 3, max of 6 decimal places shown
  ```
- use `replace()` and `trim()`. Works for any version of SQL Server.

  ```
  declare @x decimal(18,6) = 123.010000
  select @x as x1 ,
         replace( rtrim(replace(convert(varchar(32),@x),'0',' ')) , ' ' , '0' )
  ```

Comment: Let me try to be a little more clear. The column is datatype Decimal(18,6). I am casting it to float when I select it, to truncate the extra zeros. My problem is that it is returned in scientific notation. Do you have another way to do this?

Comment: @Jill -- take a a look at my amended answer.

Comment: the replace()/trim() solution worked for me! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnExpStringToDecimal]
(
     @Number AS varchar(50)
) Returns Decimal(18,7)
BEGIN 
RETURN (SELECT IIF(CHARINDEX ('E', @Number)> 0,CAST(SUBSTRING(@Number, 1, CHARINDEX ('E', @Number)-1)AS DECIMAL(18,7)) * POWER( 10.0000000,CAST(SUBSTRING(@Number, CHARINDEX ('E', @Number)+1, LEN(@Number)) AS DECIMAL(18,7))), @Number))
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that's is not the correct answer, but if you are searching for a conversion from VARCHAR scientific notation to DECIMAL and landed here like me, on SQL SERVER you can do:

```
SELECT CAST('4.51432543543E-4' AS FLOAT)
```

(tested on 2012+)