# Removing zero from decmial

Tags: sql, oracle

I  got a output like this

```
0.00234690616839645663803848176618444236941
```

the way I want is

```
2.3
```

first I remove the zero

```
select replace(0.00234690616839645663803848176618444236941,0)  from dual;
```

then I try to do the round function on it , but its giving me zero any idea how can we get this

```
select round(replace(0.00234690616839645663803848176618444236941,0) ) from dual;
```

Comment: Does the answer given at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19551983/1967396 work for you?

Comment: no it did not . i tried it  not getting what i want .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
select round(0.00234690616839645663803848176618444236941 * 1000,1) from dual;
```

Result:

```
2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

When you strip out the zeros, you are left with .23.....

`Select round (.23, 0)` will return 0, because you are telling the db to round to 0 decimal places.

If you multiply the result of your replace by 10, that will get you want you want.  Not sure what you are doing makes any sense, but it works:

```
select round (10 * (replace(0.00234690616839645663803848176618444236941,0)),1)  from dual;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c8566/2)